# Dropdown More errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script here that if i click on it drops down, as well on if i clickoutside it drops down. But i want to make it so that if i click on bottom it scrolls up. For some reason it doesnt work here. It only scrolls up if i click outside the box.

Heres an example. http://jsfiddle.net/w8mfx/

If i click on bottom it wont scroll up only if i click on outside. But i want it to work both ways.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bottom').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#content').slideDown();

});

    $('html').click(function(e) {
        //alert(1);
        if (e.target.id != 'bottom') {
            $('#content').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/w8mfx/7/

I added:

```
$('#content').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

so the user can click on the `#content` element and not trigger the slide function. That also means that the event handler for the `html` element can be simpler:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
    $('#content').slideUp();
});
```

In the jsfiddle you may notice I cached the `$('#content')` selector in a variable since it was being used in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

Use `slideToggle()`. http://jsfiddle.net/w8mfx/5/

Comment: Yeah but i dont want it to scroll down if i click within the content how do i solve that error

Comment: Just note that jQuery doesn't account for rounded borders.

Comment: I think this is what the OP is looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/w8mfx/5/ (Note, the `e.target.id` check was looking for `bottom`, not `content`.)

Comment: Still goes up on content -__-

Comment: Okay, the question was slightly ambiguous. I didn't know you didn't want it to happen if the content was clicked. Updated to @Jared's version.